# change row background of a listview when swipe

Tags: android, listview, swipe

i'm using 47deg library to implement swipe gesture for listview: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

I want to change each row's background after i'm swiping it and i have 2 problems.

First problem is When i swipe for example first row, the  background color of it change perfectly but after i scrolling the list i see background of some other rows changed. I searched a lot and find out that this problem related to reusing views in listview but i can't figure it out how should i fix my problem.

The second problem is that only first half of the list's rows effected after i swipe them. Actually when i swipe second half of rows i get error and force close. maybe this problem related to the first one, i'm not sure.

This is my Adapter class:

```
public class WordsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<WordsItem> data;
private Context context;

public WordsListAdapter(Context context, List<WordsItem> data){
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public WordsItem getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final WordsItem item = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.example_itemname);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ((SwipeListView)parent).recycle(convertView, position);

    holder.itemName.setText(item.getItemName());

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView itemName;
}

}
```

This is the activity that includes swipelistview:

```
public class WordsActivity extends Activity {

private WordsListAdapter adapter;
private List<WordsItem> data;
private int i;

private SwipeListView swipeListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);

    data = new ArrayList<WordsItem>();

    adapter = new WordsListAdapter(this, data);

    swipeListView = (SwipeListView) findViewById(R.id.example_swipe_lv_list);

    swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
      @Override
      public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        swipeListView.closeAnimate(position);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onListChanged() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onMove(int position, float x) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
            if (right) {
                swipeListView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.front).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
              } else {
                swipeListView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.front).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              }
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
          Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
      }

      @Override
      public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
          Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));
          Toast.makeText(WordsActivity.this, "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }

      @Override
      public void onClickBackView(int position) {
          Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));

          swipeListView.closeAnimate(position);//when you touch back view it will close
      }

      @Override
      public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

      }

  });

    swipeListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    reload();

    i = 0;

    for(String word : itemData){
        data.add(new WordsItem("item " + i));
        i++;
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void reload(){
    swipeListView.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_BOTH); // there are five swiping modes
    swipeListView.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL); //there are four swipe actions 
    swipeListView.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
    swipeListView.setOffsetLeft(convertDpToPixel(300f)); // left side offset
    swipeListView.setOffsetRight(convertDpToPixel(300f)); // right side offset
    swipeListView.setAnimationTime(100); // Animation time
    swipeListView.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(true);
}

public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int) px;
}

}
```

Comment: In your adapter class you already inflate xml layout "custom_row". In the xml you have to define layouts for both side of the swipe listview. eg: back and front layouts. you can change the background colors of of them..

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a `callback` in your `activity` and implement that `interface` in your adapter so you'd know which `positions` have been revealed by sending the positions through your `callback` in your `onStartOpen()` or `onOpen()` then once your adapter recognizes these positions so does `getView()` and there you can put the logic of changing background for those positions only.

PS - whenever you try to modify `listview's` individual views because of recycling you'll never get the result you were aiming for so it's important to delegate all view related tasks to your `listview's adapter`